# Original column number in a mapped function called with a count

Tags: vimscript, cursor-movement, count

Here's an example:

```
function! TestCursorPosWithCount() range
    echo virtcol('.')
endfunction

nmap <leader>c :call TestCursorPosWithCount()<CR>
```

If I press `<leader>c`, the column number will be shown correctly. But, if I do something like `2<leader>c`, the cursor is moved and the column number will be that of the final cursor position.

So, the question: how can I get the original column number inside the function? I.e. the cursor position, as it was before pressing `2` in the last example?

---

After receiving the answer, I add here my findings: a small function demo with normal & visual mappings, that can extract line & column information from the given situation:

```
function! TestCursorPosWithCount(mode) range
    if (a:mode == 'n')
        echo 'normal mode'
        echo 'count: ' . v:count
        echo 'position: [' line('.') . ':' . col('.') ']'
    else "visual mode
        echo 'visual mode: ' . visualmode()
        echo 'count: ' . v:count
        if visualmode() !=# 'V'
            echo 'range: [' a:firstline . ':' . col("'<") ' - '
                        \   a:lastline  . ':' . col("'>") ']'
        else
            echo 'range: ['  a:firstline ' - ' a:lastline ']'
        endif
    endif
endfunction

nmap <leader>c :<C-u>call TestCursorPosWithCount('n')<CR>
xmap <leader>c :call TestCursorPosWithCount('v')<CR>
```

Comment: Did you noticed that, when you remove the `<leader>` from the mapping, you have no problem calling the function at the right column ? While digging, I yet found nothing about your problem though ...

Comment: Also, what do you expect to achieve while calling your function with a range ?

Comment: See `:h func-range`. By using `range`, the function will be called *only once*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do :

```
:2call TestCursorPosWithCount()
```

... the cursor moves to the beginning of the line 2 and the function is being executed from there.

If you use `:<C-u>call TestCursorPosWithCount()` instead, the original cursor position is available, and you can also still get the count number using `v:count`.

Comment: ... but, you're right about `:2call TestCursor...` - I can solve it by using `:<C-u>call TestCursor ...>` (edited your answer a little).